# Match value from vector via regex

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to figure out how to create a regex that will match any value from a vector, then any value from a second vector repeatedly. eg:

```
nums<-c("1","2","3","4")
syms<-c("+","-","*","\")
#program output
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "+"  "-"  "*"  "/"
#does the output match values from nums,syms repeatedly?
```

eg

```
1+2     GOOD
1*2+3/4 GOOD
13+4    BAD (no symbol in between the numbers)
```

The reason I am trying this approach is that the values of `nums` will frequently change

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Or could another solution (allowing for changing 'nums' do the trick?

Comment: no it does not have to be a regex

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex `^(?:(?:1|2|3|4)[+\-*\/])+(?:1|2|3|4)$`
Replacing the groups `(?:1|2|3|4)` with the value of `nums` each time it changes.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/cI6yQ5/1)

I didn't make the `nums` a character groups in case there were numbers with two or more digits. If `nums` can only contain 1 digit numbers you can replace the groups with `[1234]` or whatever the values are.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an admittedly ugly hack assuming that your input is already a vector, named input:

```
nums<-c("1","2","3","4")
syms<-c("+","-","*","\\")

# set some stopping parameter and starting value
moveON <- TRUE
spot <- 1

while(moveOn) {
  if(input[spot] %in% nums) spot <- spot +1
  else stop(paste(input[spot], "is not a number")

  # stop loop when input is finished
  if(spot > length(input)) break

  if(input[spot] %in% syms) spot <- spot +1
  else stop(paste(input[spot], "is not a symbol")

  # stop loop when input is finished
  if(spot > length(input)) break
}

print("finished and all is well")
```